# Create Installable Trigger on value change in specified column of google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting error : "Execution failed: You do not have permission to call ScriptApp.newTrigger. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp (line 9, file "Code") [0.058 seconds total runtime]"

```js
function onEdit(e){
    var sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName()
    if(sheetName == "Config")
    {
       if(e.range.getRow()==2 && e.range.getColumn()==1){
          ScriptApp.newTrigger("sayHello")
         .timeBased()
        .everyHours(1)
        .create();
       } 
    }
}
function sayHello(){
  Logger.log("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement anything that requires authorization in a simple trigger.  Check simple trigger [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions).

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue and the solution is using installable triggers which will be easier to set up in terms of setting times as they have it in the UI.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable